# Javascript time script does not automatically switch when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck getting this script to show certain elements during the week from 7 am to 4 pm PST and outside of that show a different element off hours and on the weekends.

I created this script but my hours are not working right. The script does not automatically start at 7 AM and automatically end at 4 PM even though I manually enter my UTC offset for Los Angeles.

The elements I am trying to show are from Unbounce so it might look a bit unfamiliar.

If anyone has any suggestions getting the hours to work correctly no matter what timezone someone in, I would really appreciate it?  Thank you.

```
var d = new Date();
var localTime = d.getTime(); 
var localOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; 
var utc = localTime + localOffset;
var offset = -7 
var PST = utc + (3600000*offset);
var nd = new Date(PST);  
var CurrentDay = nd.getDay();
var BusinessHours = nd.getHours();

if (CurrentDay !== 0 || CurrentDay !== 6) { 
    if (BusinessHours >= 16 || BusinessHours <= 7 ) { 

            $("#lp-pom-box-409").hide();
            $("#lp-pom-text-341").hide();
            $("#lp-pom-text-461").show();
            $("#lp-pom-button-460").show();
            $("#lp-pom-button-209").hide();

   } else {
     
            $("#lp-pom-box-409").show();
            $("#lp-pom-text-341").show();
            $("#lp-pom-text-461").hide();
            $("#lp-pom-button-460").hide();
            $("#lp-pom-button-209").show();

   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like, your conditions are wrong, as per your statement, 1. BusinessHours should be (BusinessHours >=7 && BusinessHours <= 16), 2. If you try CurrentDay = 6, i.e. Saturday, block will execute, you should use (CurrentDay !== 0 && CurrentDay !== 6)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback! 
I actually had this code and could not get my script to work using (BusinessHours >=7 && BusinessHours <= 16) that is why I switched it to off hours. Any idea why it does not see the hours this way?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this to anyone, who struggles with dates: do not do it. There are some very good libraries that handle `dateTime` parsing, formatting, manipulation, timezones, etc. With `dateTime` there are so many edge cases, exceptions, modifications and such, that a simple calculation can easily become a nightmare.

I created a snippet using `dayjs` ([dayjs.org](https://day.js.org/en/)) just to show that it can be easily done with a utility library. Sorry, if the snippet is not exactly doing what you want, but I wasn't 100% sure that I understood your use-case correctly.

(Also, here's a list of timezones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc)
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_timezone)

// setting -7 to default offset
dayjs.tz.setDefault("America/Denver")

// setting the format
const format = "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss A"

// building the conditions for isOpen
const isSunday = (dayOfWeek) => dayOfWeek === 6
const isSaturday = (dayOfWeek) => dayOfWeek === 5
const isWorkday = (dayOfWeek) => !isSaturday(dayOfWeek) && !isSunday(dayOfWeek)

const isWorkHour = (hourOfDay) => 7 < hourOfDay && hourOfDay < 16

const areWeOpen = (dayOfWeek, hourOfDay) => isWorkday(dayOfWeek) && isWorkHour(hourOfDay)

// display/update UI functions
const toggleStatus = ["CLOSED", "OPEN"]
const status = document.getElementById("status")
const defaultTime = document.getElementById("default-time")
const utcTime = document.getElementById("utc-time")

const update = () => {
  const denverDay = dayjs().tz().day()
  const denverHour = dayjs().tz().hour()
  const isOpen = areWeOpen(denverDay, denverHour) ? 1 : 0
  status.innerHTML = toggleStatus[isOpen]
  defaultTime.innerHTML = dayjs().tz().format(format)
  utcTime.innerHTML = dayjs().utc().format()
}

update()
setInterval(update, 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.3/plugin/utc.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.3/plugin/timezone.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="business-hours">WE'RE <span id="status">OPEN</span></div><br /> DENVER:
  <div id="default-time"></div><br /> UTC:
  <div id="utc-time"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Going to give this a try!  Thanks!